# Powershell: Find/Replace pattern of ASCII control characters

Tags: powershell, scripting, ascii, control-characters

I'm trying to write a script to search the contents of a file, and when it comes across a grouping of ASCII control characters, to insert a CR/LF.

The pattern of characters I would like to replace are **[ETX][NUL][STX][ETX][SOH]**

```
    $filenames = @(Get-Childitem "E:\VendorFiles\*")

    $CR = @("[char]3 [char]0 [char]2 [char]3 [char]1")
    foreach ($file in $filenames) {$outfile = "$file" + ".txt"
    Get-Content $file | Foreach-object {
            $_ -replace $CR,"`r`n" `
             -replace [char]3,"|" `
             -replace [char]1,"{" `
             -replace "\\","\\" `
        } | Set-Content -encoding "UTF8" $outfile}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This expression:

```
@("[char]3 [char]0 [char]2 [char]3 [char]1")
```

...creates an *array* with a *single* element. You need commas between terms if you really want an array of 5 items, but `-replace` does not support arrays anyway. Also, your single element contains the *literal* characters you typed; not what you expected.

What you need is to create a simple string to feed to `-replace`; this is a bit more involved when you are dealing with non-printable characters. You had the right idea--you just have to tell PowerShell to interpolate the code expressions within your string using the `$()` notation on each expression:

```
$CR = "$([char]3)$([char]0)$([char]2)$([char]3)$([char]1)"
```

Comment: Nicely done. Quibble: `-replace` doesn't support arrays on the _RHS_ (only one _regex_ supported); however, the _LHS_ - the input string(s) - can be an array (in which case the replacement operation is performed on the array elements individually).

Answer (score 1):

[Michael Sorens' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15393976/45375) explains the problem with your approach well and offers a working solution.

To offer a simpler alternative:

```
$CR = ([char[]] (3, 0, 2, 3, 1)) -join ''
```

- `3, 0, 2, 3, 1` creates an array of integers with the Unicode code points of the characters to create.
- Cast `[char[]]` converts the code points to actual characters (`[char]`).
- `-join ''` joins the array of characters (with no separator) to for a single *string*.

Comment: Thanks, @mkelement0, for the improvement!

Answer (score 0):

I have a function in a script that does something like this.  Not sure if this will help you:

```
# This function will make a new file that has custom comments
# it will comment out "rollback tran"
# it will uncomment out "--commit tran"
function CommentAndUncomment($TheScript)
{
    PrintTextAndTime("About to run this SQL file: $TheScript")
    PrintTextAndTime("Will comment out 'rollback tran' and uncomment '--commit tran'")
    $content = Get-Content $TheScript
    $content | 
      ForEach-Object { 
        if ($_ -clike "*ROLLBACK TRAN;*") { 
          $_ -replace "ROLLBACK TRAN;", "--ROLLBACK TRAN;"
        } 
        elseif ($_ -clike "*--COMMIT TRAN;*") { 
          $_ -replace "--COMMIT TRAN;", "COMMIT TRAN;"
        }
        else{
            $_
        }
      } | 
      Set-Content $ModifiedCommentsFile
    echo $ModifiedCommentsFile
    sqlcmd -i $ModifiedCommentsFile
    del $ModifiedCommentsFile
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not help.